# Range.insertHtml() fails on Word Online build 16.0.11813.33700

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

Rnage.insertHtml() works well on Word Application, and worked well before on Word Online.

But it seems that there is a new release recently for Word Online, it doesn't work any more on Word Online with following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: Cannot read property 'XWa' of null
>       at new RuntimeError (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:11720:22)
>       at RequestContext.ClientRequestContext.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:14496:12)
>       at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:14403:29

Comment: This should be a bug, we will take a look. Thanks for reporting.